# In Ansible, is there a way to make deployment in a specific order?

Tags: ansible

I’m using Ansible since a few months now, and I have a little issue with deployment order on different hosts.

I have 8 servers:

- 4 reverse proxy apache
- 4 tomcat servers

When I make deployments on these servers, I have to stop the first Apache to perform the deployment on the first Tomcat. When Tomcat1 is done, I have to start Apache1. After I continue the same deployments on all servers.

If my hosts file is:

```
[apache-servers]
apache1
apache2
apache3
apache4

[tomcat-servers]
tomcat1
tomcat2
tomcat3
tomcat4
```

Then, Ansible stops ALL Apaches, ALL Tomcats, makes deployment, and restarts all.

So, I have found a trick to do what I want. I have to run a shell script to rewrite the host file before running ansible-playbooks.

Is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: Maybe you can use a combination of delegate ans serial directives: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

Comment: Another way could be a loop over groups and order the hosts in groups they belong to (one apache with one tomcat in a group): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-loop-over-a-list-of-hosts-in-a-group-inside-of-a-template

Comment: Maybe you could find useful rolling upgrades http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_rolling_upgrade.html

Comment: Also, you can use strategies in order to not execute in a linear way: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `serial: 1` in your play and it will run the play on one host at a the time.